# Loading web images and showing like a slideshow

Tags: android, image, slideshow

I want to show images from web in a slideshow.I used ViewFlipper but it doesn't work for web images.I don't want to use third party library. Can somebody please point me to an example where i can show web images in slideshow.Is it possible using Glide? Please help

Comment: try with horizontal recyclerview

Comment: theat are 2 different questions. 1) load image from web. 2) show image in a slideshow. Solve them separately.

Comment: Agree with @VladMatvienko.

Also, Glide is a third party library :)

Comment: @MiguelCatalan is right. As I didn't notice, and he did - `I don't want to use third party library` and `.Is it possible using Glide` are 2 incompatible things.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could elaborate on why you don't want to use third party librairies.

If using libraries from Google is acceptable for you, a solution could be to use a ViewPager containing a NetworkImageView.

This widget is part of Volley library and allows you to display images from a URL.

If you need help with it, let me know I'll post a piece of code.

Have a nice day :)